# How to design a website with zero user data?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, user-research, users

Whenever I think of this condition, I get confused. If my business is dependent user data, then how should I think of the design from scratch? What should I do to collect data from users or encourage them to use the website? I know what to do once I have enough data set but I have no idea with 0 users.

How did Facebook or Instagram get started with no users?

Comment: signalvnoise has a lot of discussions about designing `blank slates` / screens that don't yet have data. In a way to encourage user interaction. Might be useful.  Check out https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3210-backstage-designing-the-new-basecamp-blank-slates or https://signalvnoise.com/posts/90-design-decisions-backpack-page-blank-slate

Comment: What do you mean your business is "dependent [on] user data"? What do you do with that data? Can users accomplish their goals on your site without giving you any info about themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create a call to action

If there is no data available, display a big, centered text, saying something like `Nothing here yet` with a nice, attention-grabbing image (Preferably single color).

Below that, create a call to action. Something like `Get started by adding new content` or `Get started by pressing the plus-icon below`, etc. You can even integrate a button into this "Nothing here"-Message. It's a good guiding system.

Best color for this would be grey text color on a grey background. Google Drive is a very good example. It can't be mixed up with content and provides a clear CTA (Drop your files here or use the button "New").

[image: Google Drive empty folder]

For comparison: Thats what it looks like when the folder isn't empty:

[image: Google Drive folder not empty]

Facebook is doing something similar. You maybe know the call to action they place next to their like-buttons: `Be the first of your friends to like this`. Or below videos or posts: `Be the first to comment`.

[image: Be the first to comment][Image source](https://disqus.com/home/channel/discussdisqus/discussion/channel-discussdisqus/how_can_i_translate_be_the_first_to_comment/)